# error in getting date from MS Access database?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, devexpress

Am using DevExpresss Winform. I used DateEdit to store date and in access database I used datatype as Date/Time. Now I stored Date [`19-11-2013`] and then while retrieve the date is come with time. like this [`19-11-2013 PM 12:00:00`]. But I dont need time. How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an error. Even if in your database you have a `Date` data type you get a time when you use a `DateTime` variable in `C#`. What you see is the default time 12:00 PM or 00:00 in 24h format. Note that is not `Date` data type in C#.

If you don't want to see the time value, just format it accordingly 
[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008,4, 10);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("d", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
// Displays 04/10/2008
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, yeah i checked and its working fine but I need to change in this code How to edit this line. Help me `DateTime date = CBL_Date.DateTime;`

Comment: What do you need to do? try `string myDate = CBL_Date.ToString("d");`

Comment: Hi Vland, Am getting error like best OverLoaded Method found.

Comment: @SriHari i don't understand, create a new question and paste your code in there. This question is closed